# Manager() works through python but fails in cx_freeze built environment

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, multiprocessing, cx-freeze

I am facing this curious issue of Manager() call in python multiprocessing. When I invoke my program normally through shell, it all goes fine. But the same thing built with cx_freeze fails. Here is the code sample

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Manager, Queue
if conf.shared_dict == None:
    manager = Manager()
    conf.shared_dict = manager.dict()
    conf.shared_dict['seed'] = 0
parent_conn, child_conn= Pipe()

The failure happens in Manager() call and following is the stack trace.

File C:\Users\data-sync\service_api.py, line 93, in message_broker
    manager = Manager()
File C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py, line 99, in Manager
    m.start()
File C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py, line 528, in start
    self.address = reader.recv()
EOFError
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had not called

```
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

Works great after adding this.